# Triggering a link via a checkbox in only HTML and Javascript

Tags: html, css, checkbox, anchor, url-scheme

Is there a way of launching a link from clicking/tapping on a checkbox with only HTML and CSS (no JavaScript)?

I'm scripting something for personal use and looking for a way to launch a [URL scheme](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/shortcuts/apd621a1ad7a/ios) by checking a checkbox.

It is trivial to write a checkbox that "has" a link:

`<a href="kmtrigger://macro=some%20macro"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="done" value="value"></a> Test`

Hovering over the checkbox reveals the link (as shown in [this CodePen sample of the above code](https://codepen.io/ryanjamurphy/pen/zYGNJEG)). Still, I cannot get the link to launch. It seems like the checkbox action "absorbs" clicks.

I have tried giving the link a higher `z-index`, but it had no effect.

(There are other ways of achieving this that I will probably pursue, but this is the simplest if it is possible!)

Comment: try onchange="window.open('kmtrigger://macro=some%20macro', '_blank')" in checkbox

Comment: Thanks @ShivPatne. I really didn’t expect _any_ scripting to work in this context, but this did. I used `_self` instead of `_blank` however.